# Can I read the 'real' mobile GPS coordinates from a website?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, web, w3c

I did a website and I want to read the 'real' position GPS on mobile (Android & iPhone).
When I try set the location on my website from my Android with [W3C](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) javascript method the GPS is not enabled and the position is set by IP (When I try with Google Maps app the GPS is enabled and blink on the status bar).
Is any way for read the GPS (real GPS) from a web on a mobile?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With HTML5 you can do that. You need to check Geolocation API: [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/geolocation.html) and [W3C Geolocation API Specification](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html)

The simplest example looks like:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( 
        function (position) {  
            do_something(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
        }, 
        function (error){
            switch(error.code){
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    // Timeout
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Position unavailable
                    break;
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    // Permission denied
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    // Unknown error
                    break;
                default: break;
           }
        }
    );
}
```

Probably you're also interesting in some browser specific implementations: [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_geolocation), [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg593067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/)

**Updated.** 
As Mozilla said [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_geolocation), *Devices with a GPS, for example, can take a minute or more to get a GPS fix, so less accurate data (IP location or wifi) may be returned to getCurrentPosition() to start.*

So, if you need to have high accuracy (like GPS only), use `watchPosition` instead of `getCurrentPosition`.

Comment: Thanks gakhov, but with that method, the mobile is not using the real GPS (not blink on status bar) :O

Comment: It's strange. The mobile enabled the GPS... mobile not found anything in 3" and ask about Share my Position... If I admit know the Position the mobile just set the Position by GSM and the mobile remains search by the GPS signal.
I need that the mobile not use GSM triangulation :( Could be that possible, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found the problem :) Just use if(position.coords.accuracy<=MIN_GPS_ACCURACY) on function (position).
Thanks gakhov!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the W3C specification, you might need to use the third argument of both watchPosition and getCurrentPosition, which is a [PositionOptions interface](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position_options_interface) to set enableHighAccuracy to true, else, using its default value false, the GPS won't necessarily be switched on by the device.